# How to remove "All files" from the file dailog

Tags: html

How to remove `"All files"` from the file dialog.

I have to accept only `svg` files. So I don't need `"All files"` options in the file dialog.

Below is the HTML code I have written:

```
<input type="file" accept=".svg" />
```

How do I achieve this?

Comment: Please write your code below.

Comment: <input type="file" accept=".svg" />

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
<input type="file" accept="image/svg+xml" />
```

Comment: using chrome and in the code i have used accept="image/svg+xml"

Answer (score 0):

There is no way you can limit it specially for svg files only. However you can user `accept="image/*"` to accept only image type of files. If you pass `accept="image/svg"` or `accept="image/svg+xml"` the file type shown in dialog box will be custom.

**[Read this](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_accept.asp)** to know about the accepted filters. **[This](http://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/media-types.xhtml)** is a full reference of all media types.

See this **[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/k0a6bw31/)**.

Comment: so,cant we remove "All files" even after we put a filter to accept only particular file type?

Comment: Yes you can remove all files. After you add filter only files related to that filter type will be shown.

Comment: I have edited my answer to put more details. look at the added links.

Comment: Sorry, I am still getting  "All files" in the file dailog with the code given above.

Comment: Please tell what browser and browser version you are using. You have added accept="image/*" or accept="image/svg+xml"

Answer (score 0):

If I recall correctly, you cannot ask the browser to restrict file types - since you do not have control over the file dialog the browser chooses to display.

Your best bet, as per other answers is to "advise" the browser of the MIME types you're going to accept. If the browser respects that, then great, otherwise you're stuck I'm afraid.